# how can i set an onclick event listener on the sides of my html/javascript CUBE code

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to code an html/javascript and css cube and so far the example i found online rotates or moves at the press of a radio button, but i want to set an onclick event listener on all the sides so when the clicks a side it moves

i have tried using this "document.getElementById("cube").addEventListener("click", changeSide);" but nothing happens

```js
var cube = document.querySelector('.cube');
var radioGroup = document.querySelector('.radio-group');
var currentClass = '';

function changeSide() {
  var checkedRadio = radioGroup.querySelector(':checked');
  var showClass = 'show-' + checkedRadio.value;
  if ( currentClass ) {
    cube.classList.remove( currentClass );
  }
  cube.classList.add( showClass );
  currentClass = showClass;
}
// set initial side
changeSide();
            radioGroup.addEventListener( 'change', changeSide );

document.getElementById("cube").addEventListener("click", changeSide);
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 80px;
  perspective: 400px;
}

.cube {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(-100px);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.cube.show-front  { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(   0deg); }
.cube.show-right  { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY( -90deg); }
.cube.show-back   { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(-180deg); }
.cube.show-left   { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(  90deg); }
.cube.show-top    { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX( -90deg); }
.cube.show-bottom { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(  90deg); }

.cube__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.cube__face--front  { background: hsla(  0, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }
.cube__face--right  { background: hsla( 60, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }
.cube__face--back   { background: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }
.cube__face--left   { background: hsla(180, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }
.cube__face--top    { background: hsla(240, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }
.cube__face--bottom { background: hsla(300, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }

.cube__face--front  { transform: rotateY(  0deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--right  { transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--back   { transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--left   { transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--top    { transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--bottom { transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }

label { margin-right: 10px; }
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div  class="cube">
    <div id ="cube" onclick="changeSide" class="cube__face cube__face--front">46</div>
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--back">97</div>
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--right">23</div>
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--left">54</div>
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--top">32</div>
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--bottom">11</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="radio-group">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="front" checked /> front
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="right" /> right
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="back" /> back
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="left" /> left
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="top" /> top
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="bottom" /> bottom
  </label>
</p>
```

i expect it all the sides to be clickable but it does nothing when i click it

Comment: When you click it, the function checks the radio button state, and sees that the selected side is already showing.

Comment: i think you wanted to do document.querySelector('#cube') instead of document.querySelector('.cube'). There are 2 divs one with cude class, other with cude id.

Comment: Say for instance the active class is 'show-front'. When you click the box it just tries to set the active class to 'show-front' again, and since its already in that position, it does nothing

Comment: Add `console.log( 'inChangeSide');` to the changeSide function and you'll see that our onClick handler is triggering.